# Dynamically instantiating class from same module causes main to run twice

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a module named `dynamic_cls_ex.py` and two classes named `FooButton` and `BarButton`. I am using the below code to dynamically instantiate the class I am interested in from a string.

**The problem:** I'm using `__import__` to import the module, which causes `main` to run twice. *this is my elementary understanding. Please feel free to give me a better explanation on what's actually going on*

```
# !/usr/bin/python

class FooButton(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'I am a foo button'

class BarButton(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'I am a bar button'


method = 'Foo'
class_name = '%sButton' % method
module = __import__('dynamic_cls_ex')
Button = getattr(module, class_name)
Button()


# OUTPUT:
# >> I am a foo button
# >> I am a foo button
```

**How can I dynamically instantiate a class without needing to import the module I'm currently running?**

Comment: Do you have an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard in the main function of `dynamic_cls_ex`?

Comment: .... trying that now.

Comment: works. If you want to write out an answer, I'd love to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you haven't specified what's in `dynamic_cls_ex.py`, but I assume it has some top-level code that actually runs (which is what you're calling the `main` function, I think).

This code is run whenever its enclosing python file is itself run at the top level of the interpreter, or when it is imported (with [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)  you're explicitly circumventing the check to not reload already-present modules).

But you can force code to be only run when it is actually run at the top level by checking for [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) -- "this module represents the (otherwise anonymous) scope in which the interpreter’s main program executes". So if you wrap the top-level code in `if __name__ == "__main__":` it will only run from the main program, and not when imported.

See also [What does `if __name__ == "__main__":` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a guard for `if __name__ == '__main__'` and placing the code that was in the global scope prevented the code from running twice.

When I run the below code:

```
print __name__
module = __import__('dynamic_cls_ex')

# I get:
# >> __main__
# >> dynamic_cls_ex
```

So I changed the code to have a guard like the above snippet, I got the following output, which demonstrates why the guard worked, and that I didn't get any more duplicates.

```
# placed below FooButton BarButton class definitions

print __name__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    method = 'Foo'
    class_name = '%sButton' % method
    module = __import__('dynamic_cls_ex')
    Button = getattr(module, class_name)
    Button()

# Output:
# >> __main__
# >> dynamic_cls_ex
# >> I am a foo button
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use globals() function to get a dictionary with global name bindings. Then you can access this dictionary to get your class.